# Applying spark window function on subset of a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to force spark to only apply a window function on a specified subset of a dataframe, while the actual window has access to rows outside of this subset. Let me go through an example:

I have a spark dataframe that has been saved to hdfs. The dataframe contains events, so each row has a timestamp an id and an integer feature. Also there is a column that I calculate, which is a sum window function made like this:

```
df = spark.table("some_table_in_hdfs")

w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("feat_int_sum", F.sum("feat_int").over(w))

df.show()
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|      date|feat_int| id|feat_int_sum|
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|2018-08-10|       5|  0|           5|
|2018-08-12|      27|  0|          32|
|2018-08-14|       3|  0|          35|
|2018-08-11|      32|  1|          32|
|2018-08-12|     552|  1|         584|
|2018-08-16|       2|  1|         586|
+----------+--------+---+------------+
```

When I do a load of new data from a different source, I would like to append to the above dataframe in hdfs. In order to do this, I have to apply the window function to the new data as well. I would like to union the two dataframes so that the window function has access to the "old" `feat_int` values to do the sum over.

```
df_new = spark.table("some_new_table")
df_new.show()
+----------+--------+---+
|      date|feat_int| id|
+----------+--------+---+
|2018-08-20|      65|  0|
|2018-08-23|       3|  0|
|2018-08-24|       4|  0|
|2018-08-21|      69|  1|
|2018-08-25|      37|  1|
|2018-08-26|       3|  1|
+----------+--------+---+

df_union = df.union(df_new.withColumn("feat_int_sum", F.lit(None)))
df_union.show()
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|      date|feat_int| id|feat_int_sum|
+----------+--------+---+------------+
|2018-08-10|       5|  0|           5|
|2018-08-12|      27|  0|          32|
|2018-08-14|       3|  0|          35|
|2018-08-20|      65|  0|        null|
|2018-08-23|       3|  0|        null|
|2018-08-24|       4|  0|        null|
|2018-08-11|      32|  1|          32|
|2018-08-12|     552|  1|         584|
|2018-08-16|       2|  1|         586|
|2018-08-21|      69|  1|        null|
|2018-08-25|      37|  1|        null|
|2018-08-26|       3|  1|        null|
+----------+--------+---+------------+
```

The problem is, that I would like to apply the sum window function on `df_union` but only on the rows with `null` in `feat_int_sum`. The reason is that I don't want to recalculate the window function for all the values that are already calculated in `df`. So the desired result would be something like this:

```
+----------+--------+---+------------+-----------------+
|      date|feat_int| id|feat_int_sum|feat_int_sum_temp|
+----------+--------+---+------------+-----------------+
|2018-08-10|       5|  0|           5|             null|
|2018-08-12|      27|  0|          32|             null|
|2018-08-14|       3|  0|          35|             null|
|2018-08-20|      65|  0|        null|              100|
|2018-08-23|       3|  0|        null|              103|
|2018-08-24|       4|  0|        null|              107|
|2018-08-11|      32|  1|          32|             null|
|2018-08-12|     552|  1|         584|             null|
|2018-08-16|       2|  1|         586|             null|
|2018-08-21|      69|  1|        null|              655|
|2018-08-25|      37|  1|        null|              692|
|2018-08-26|       3|  1|        null|              695|
+----------+--------+---+------------+-----------------+
```

I tried wrapping the window function in a `when` statement like this:

```
df_union.withColumn("feat_int_sum_temp", F.when(F.col('date') > '2018-08-16', F.sum('feat_int').over(w))
```

But looking at the spark explain plan, it seems that it will run the window function for all rows, and afterwards apply the when conditon.
The whole reason I don't want to run the window function on the old rows, is that I'm dealing with some really big tables, and I don't want to waste computational ressources recalculating values that will not be used.
After this step I would coalesce the `feat_int_sum` and the `feat_int_sum_temp` columns, and append only the new part of the data to hdfs.
I would appreciate any hints on how to force spark to only apply the window function on the specified subset, while the actual window has access to rows outside of this subset.

Comment: Can you try something like this, do a lag operation and sum only feat_int + feat_int_sum for lag -1 record when a null is found in feat_int_sum column.

Comment: In your example, it would only be possible to calculate the value for the new rows if you at least have the last value from the old rows, correct?

Comment: Sounds all very convoluted, I would try and redesign the approach in all honesty.

Comment: @KSNidhin The problem is that the window can be of arbitrary size, I would need to go case by case if I choose this approach. I would like a more general solution.

Comment: @Nanda No because the window might look further back than 1 row.

Comment: @thebluephantom do you have any suggestions? - Problem itself is pretty basic, but my description of it might be a bit convoluted.